# Capture the swipe effect to navigate to next page in HTML5 Ipad App

Tags: javascript, ipad, html

I'm making an offline version of an online products catalogue for the Ipad. It will be written in HTML5 / JS and utilise offline image caching and localstorage.

I want to be able to introduce the same UI interactions as come with the Ipad in terms of swiping. So if the user swipes from right to left, it will load the next product. If they swipe from left to right, it will load the previous image.

How do I capture this with Javascript ?

Answer (score 5):

You can have a look at the events supported by mobile Safari here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

`touchstart`, `touchmove` and `touchend` events in particular

Or, if you don't want to reinvent the wheel, you can have a look at these scripts:
http://cubiq.org/swipeview

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/swipe

Comment: I can't stress enough that when looking through various documentation (either official from Apple or on programming websites) you need to pay close attention to the structure of the touch event object. The hierarchies of properties within the touch event object - especially those related to what you're trying to do - are significantly different than with a standard "desktop" event object. This really threw me for a loop when I first started dealing with touch events.